# Registration form php mysql html

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

```
    <?php include("header.php")?>
<?php include("menu.php")?>
<div id="registrationPage">
<div id="registrationDiv" ></div>
<fieldset id="registrationFieldPos">
<legend><h3>Register</h3></legend>
<form id="registrationForm" action="registrationaction.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr>
<td><label>First Name :</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Last Name :</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="lname" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Username :</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Password :</label></td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Confirm Password :</label></td>
<td><input type="password" name="passwordconfirm" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Email :</label></td>
<td><input type="email" name="email" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Image :</label></td>
<td><input type="file" name="fileUpload" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Country :</label></td>
<td>
<select name="country">
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mutetistore') or die('connection error'.  mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($connection, 'mutetistore');


$sql = "SELECT * FROM apps_countries" ;
$results = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($results)):;

?>
<option value=" <?php echo $result['country_name']; ?> "> <?php echo $result['country_name'];?> </option>

 <?php endwhile; ?> 

</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Languages :</label></td>
<td>
<label>English <input type="checkbox" name="Languages[]" value = "English" /></label>
<label>French<input type="checkbox" name="Languages[]" value = "French" /></label>
<label>Swahili<input type="checkbox" name="Languages[]" value = "Swahili" /></label>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Gender:</label></td>
<td>
<label>Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value = "male"/></label>
<label>Female</label><input type="radio" name="gender" value = "female"/>
</td>

</tr>


<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="save" value = "registered"/></td>
</tr>


</table>



</form>
</fieldset>
<div id="divEnd">
</div>
</div>
<?php include("footer.php")?>
<?php


require('databaseconn.php');
if(isset($_POST['save'])  ) {
     $firstname = $_POST['fname'];
     $lastname = $_POST['lname'];
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     $passwordconfirm = $_POST['passwordconfirm'];
     $country = $_POST['country'];
     $gender = $_POST['gender'];
     $Languages = $_POST['Languages'];
     $imagename = $_FILES['fileUpload']['name'];
     $imagesize = $_FILES['fileUpload']['size'];
     $imagetmp = $_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'];
     if(empty( $firstname)) {
        echo "please enter username";
     }else if(empty( $lastname)) {
        echo "please enter lastname";
     }else if(empty( $username)) {
        echo "please enter username";
     }else if(empty( $password)) {
        echo "please enter password";
     }else if(empty( $password !== $passwordconfirm)) {
        echo "password do not match";
     }else if(empty( $country)) {
        echo "please select your country ";
     }else if(empty( $gender)) {
        echo "please select your gender ";
     }else if(empty( $imagename)) {
        echo "please select image";
     }else {


$uploadFolder = "Uploads/";
$filename = rand(1000,100000)."-".$imagename;
$filenameUpload = move_uploaded_file($imagetm, $uploadFolder, $filename);


$sql = "INSERT INTO `register` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `password`, `country`, `gender`, `language`, `imageName`, `imageSize`, `imageTemp`) 
VALUES (NULL, '$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$password', '$country', '$gender', '$Languages', '$filenameUpload', '$imagesize', '$imagetmp')";      


     }

}



?>

<?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?><br>
<?php echo $_POST["lname"]; ?><br>
<?php echo $_POST["username"]; ?><br>
<?php echo $_POST["password"]; ?><br>
<?php echo $_POST["passwordconfirm"]; ?><br>
<?php echo $_POST["country"]; ?><br>
<?php echo $_POST["gender"]; ?><br>
<?php echo $_POST["password"]; ?><br>
<?php echo $_POST["passwordconfirm"]; ?><br>
<?php echo $_POST["country"]; ?><br>
```

This code is giving me headache. Could someone spot the error? I have tried it for a day without a solution. I want it to submit data to database (image ,checkbox,radio,etc). I want it to put all the selected checkboxs to database. I will later learn about the `implode`, `exlode`, to add commas to the code.

Comment: What error? This just looks like a code dump to me.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific..  what happens? We're not gonna read through all the code and guess..

Comment: you aren't even executing a query. you are just saving your query-string to the `$sql` variable.

Comment: i want the code to save the data to database after i click submit button

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injections... that is, if you ever would execute the SQL-query.

Comment: I was looking for a [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) here because you've recklessly disregarded any [escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) when composing that query, but you don't actually execute the query, you just declare a query string and then **throw it in the garbage**. This is actually safe code due to it's non-functionality. **Be very careful** when writing SQL code. A tiny mistake can cost you huge.

Comment: `while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($results)):;` <<< you see that semi-colon? It "ends" the statement and you won't get an error about it, since it's a valid character.

Comment: `$_POST['Languages'];` is an array so `$Languages` will also be an array. You cannot store an array into MYSQL, well not like you have tried. Also remember checkbox's are only sent to the PHP script when they are checked, so that array will not always have the same dimensions

Comment: I get the feeling you are trying to SPRINT the 100m before you have learned to CRAWL. Maybe some quality time with some books and tutorials is where you need to be right now

Comment: Please read this!  http://bobby-tables.com

Answer (score 0):

First two lines:

```
<?php include("header.php")?>  <---- End the statement with ;
<?php include("menu.php")?> <---- Here too!
```

On Other Lines:

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($results)):; <---What is this? It should be { //Code here  
and The closing of while loop should be this! ->} not <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Here:

```
}else if(empty( $password !== $passwordconfirm)) { // Your Operation should be != and not !==
```

Maybe your id should be declared as an Auto-increment. And not to be added as NULL.

Youre full of headaches.. hahaha